# Re-writing Matlab code in C++

Tags: c++, matlab

Basically, I'm trying to split a massive 1D vector into blocks of a given size which is passed through the function. The function should return a 2D vector and then I can just access the different blocks. I have found a suitable algoritm to do this, however, it is in Matlab and I do not understand how to place the elements inside the 2D vector.

MatLab Code:

```
function f = block(v, N, M)

n = length(v);
maxblockstart = n - N + 1;
lastblockstart = maxblockstart - mod(maxblockstart-1 , M);

numblocks = (lastblockstart-1)/M + 1;

f = zeros(numblocks,N);

for i = 1:numblocks
for j = 1:N
  f(i,j) = v((i-1)*M+j);
end
end
```

Here is my attempt in C++ (Sorry if it's bad):

```
vector<iniMatrix> subBlocks(vector<int>& theData, int N, int M)
{
// This method splits the vector into blocks
// Each block has size N.
// and consecutive blocks differ 

int n = theData.size();
int maxblockstart = n - N+1;
int lastblockstart = maxblockstart - (maxblockstart-1 % M);

int numblocks = (lastblockstart-1)/M + 1;

vector<int> subBlock;
vector<iniMatrix> block;

for(unsigned i=0; (i < numblocks); i++)
{
    for(unsigned j=0; (j < N); j++)
    {
        subBlock.push_back(theData[(i-1*M+j)]);

        block.push_back(subBlock);
    }
}

return block;
}
```

This code compiles, but, when even trying to output the size of the block, i get: Segmentation fault: 11.. Any ideas?

The data being passed through the function is: 
N = 600
M = 200

I hope someone can help me, thank you :)

Comment: is you loop not working ? or do you just want the explanation of the Mathlab loop ?

Comment: An explanation please and also the loop does not work, error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >) (unsigned int)’. Thank you

Comment: Now i added some more info about differences about array start index and for-loops between matlab and C++

Comment: which line trigger that error? ( probably the call to your function ) , we need to see more code here

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my post to include the new code.. It just segments .. Any idea?

Comment: Solved it!! How do I mark this as solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In c and c++, array indices start from zero. This is important to keep in mind if you're using array length functions. So, you should replace the `i-1` multiplier with `i` and start the counting from zero. The loop condition:

```
for (unsigned j=1; (j < N); j++)
```

will start from `1` and end at the `N-1` -- a total of `N-1` times. But,

```
for (unsigned j=0; (j < N); j++)
```

will start from `0` and end at `N-1` -- a total of `N` times.

**In Matlab: for-loops start from first boundary then end at second boundary**

If you feel that you *must* start from index `1`,

```
for (unsigned j=1; (j < N+1); j++)
```

will do `N` iterations while still starting at `1`. But please keep in mind that when you declare an array in C/C++, the index to the first element is zero.